# Kafka connect delays between successive Puts

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

I have a Kafka connector which is working fine but it only get messages every 25 seconds or so in blocks of 300k or more. I would like to receive messages whenever the Put request has been returned instead of such a long wait.

I’m using Kafka 0.10.0 so can someone tell me why is there just a long delay between successive Puts from Kafka connect.

Thanks

Comment: Which connector are you using?

Comment: Home grown connector using Kafka connect 0.10.0

Comment: Sorry without some code, or more information I don't think you're going to get much help. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask